# UnityScript vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I know there's a difference between the languages, such as classes etc.

What I wonder is this: If UnityScript is different from Javascript, why does the Unity3D documentation give you the options to pick between C# and JS when you look through it? Shouldn't it be a choice between C# and US?

Meanwhile, here on Stack Overflow, people generally make the effort to correct people who call it Javascript. Why is that?

Comment: JS and US have enough differences that it's important to distinguish between them when you ask a question. Otherwise you might just waste people's time when their answer is incompatible with what you're actually using. On Unity's site on the other hand there's no danger of confusion because it's obvious from the context that they're always talking about Unity and never about non-Unity JavaScript.

Comment: Because I'm still trying to understand all the differences here and forgot the java tag was irrelevant. I don't have the know-how of every single thing regarding programming so I'm still getting the hang of the basic differences. I wouldn't even post this question if I could find an answer somewhere.

Comment: @Juhana Thank you, that's all I wanted to know, shame I had to waste some reputation to figure it out but I guess it was worth it, considering I did it to better understand and be able to better contribute here in the future.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. It's a valid question in the context of Unity's use of terminology, which historically has been muddled.

Comment: I have edited the question and voted for re-opening.

Comment: @Ghopper21 I agree. I think it's shocking that Unity continues to use the term "javascript" for their proprietary scripting language, even with the new version 5 release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity uses a custom JavaScript variant also known as UnityScript which it historically and still today commonly (but inconsistently) refers to as "JavaScript," including as you note in its own script documentation.

This is incorrect in terms of the meaning of the term "JavaScript" in the programming world at large (i.e. beyond the Unity community). UnityScript is definitely *not* JavaScript. They are incompatible languages with fundamental differences. From a strict correctness point of view, yes, Unity *should* use "UnityScript" in its documentation.

The incorrect usage doesn't tend to be problem within the Unity community, within which it is assumed that "JavaScript" means the JavaScript used by Unity. In fact, it's possible that using the term "UnityScript" could cause confusion within the Unity community, because the term "JavaScript" has historically been and continues to be more commonly used, and it's possible many non-programmers within the Unity community don't even realize Unity is actually using a variant JavaScript, as opposed to actual JavaScript.

However, outside of the Unity community, including here on Stack Overflow, using the term "JavaScript" to mean anything other than the actual JavaScript will cause confusion, which is why it's important to say "UnityScript" here.

Incidentally, Unity adds to the potential confusion, both within and without the Unity community, by not being consistent. In its [release notes for version 5](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.0), it used both "JavaScript" and "UnityScript" interchangeably. In a [blog entry about an important scripting change](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/), it used the term "UnityScript-aka-Javascript."

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer was very informative and much needed. As both a beginner programmer and new user here on Stack Overflow, it quickly became confusing when people started correcting these terms within seconds of a post.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Juhana, thank you for the answer.

> JS and US have enough differences that it's important to distinguish
>   between them when you ask a question. Otherwise you might just waste
>   people's time when their answer is incompatible with what you're
>   actually using. On Unity's site on the other hand there's no danger of
>   confusion because it's obvious from the context that they're always
>   talking about Unity and never about non-Unity JavaScript.