# Using PointerEventData returns error: "Unexpected symbol"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, cursor-position

I am new to C# and decided to start using it for now since most of the Unity tutorials are focused on it and I've never used JavaScript for anything other than webpages.

For the most part everything was working until I tried using the **Vector2.MoveTowards** method:

```
    void OnMouseDown() {
    int weapCoolDown = 1;
    Instantiate(bullet_player);
    Vector2.MoveTowards(GameObject.Find("player-1"), Vector2 PointerEventData.position(), float p1BulletSpeed);
}
```

[Errors reported by Unity console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N51H.png)

I tried removing Vector2, then it asks me to add **EventSystems** but it's already there inside **UnityEngine**. I fix that and then it says it doesnt exist? Then I fix that and it just gives me a bunch of other errors that I dont even really know how to remove.

And when I try using an identifier instead, it will assign it but it won't let me use it and it says Unexpected Symbol like usual.

The Unity manual doesn't provide enough detail or examples to really help me solve this, is there a class or reference I am missing or should I just try and use an alternate method?

Comment: "I've never used JavaScript for anything other than webpages.".... Not sure what that has to do with your question. Your code is C#. This is not Unityscript. It is not Javascript.

Comment: @Programmer Ok then but I think since I already know JS pretty well I might start switching to that. C# doesn't have quite the same syntax so I have to start learning a new language altogether or start with js again.
I'm trying to stick with c# when I'm working with Unity because most of the video tutorials I've found mainly focus on it

Comment: I am not saying you should not use C#. I am telling you that the code in your question is C# code not Javascript. In the past, you could use Unityscript/Javascript but that is now [discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523239/is-unityscript-javascript-discontinued). You have no option but to learn C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you should review in your code:

The [`Vector2.MoveTowards()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) is not being called with the proper parameters. `GameObject.Find()` will return a gameObject, not a Vector2. If you're looking for the current position of player 1, you should construct a Vector2 from player 1's transform.position.

```cs
Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2();
playerPosition.x = GameObject.Find("player-1").transform.position.x;
playerPosition.y = GameObject.Find("player-1").transform.position.y;
```

Any use of [PointerEventData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html) requires a using directive for [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html). In order to include it, add `using UnityEngine.EventSystem` with the rest of your using directives.

The Vector2 prefix before `PointerEventData.position()` is invalid. It's not an explicit typecast, as it's not in parenthesis, but typecasts aren't needed since position will return a Vector2.

`pointerEventData.position` is a property that draws from an object reference. However, the implementation of `PointerEventData.position()` is improperly using this as a static method. Since it's not actually a static method, but a dynamic property, it will fail to compile and draw errors.

For pointerEventData to exist, it needs to originate from an event which retrieves eventData. Unfortunately, `OnMouseDown()` does not do this. However, an interface method from [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) called [`OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick.html) has the pointerEventData you need.

Refactoring your existing code, this is closer to the functionality you're looking for.

```
// Add this "using" directive
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

// Be sure to implement the interface of IPointerClickHandler
public class NameOfYourScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {

    //
    // Additional Code in your class. . . .
    // 

    // Replace OnMouseDown() with this.
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData) {
        Instantiate(bullet_player);

        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2();
        playerPosition.x = GameObject.Find("player-1").transform.position.x;
        playerPosition.y = GameObject.Find("player-1").transform.position.y;

        Vector2.MoveTowards(playerPosition, pointerEventData.position, p1BulletSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is flawless and has no errors. Thanks for the help
I think next time I should start using JavaScript since I already know that language and I'm still new to C#.

Comment: Just a heads up, Unity uses a custom JavaScript variant also known as UnityScript which it historically and still today commonly (but inconsistently) refers to as "JavaScript." UnityScript can only be used to script Unity. It is not interoperable with external JavaScript libraries so you cannot import things like Node or Threes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194823/unityscript-vs-javascript for more information.